# SQL query to show top x records with evenly distributed values

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a database of contacts at companies. Multiple contacts per company in different departments. Each company has turnover and industry data attached to it.

I need to write a query that shows the top 10 most recently added contacts (unix timestamp) but i don't want it to be all Marketing contacts (even if the top 10 are), i would like to look at the top 100 instead and get 10 contacts out that are from different departments. So instead of the top 10 being all marketing, there might be 2 marketing, 2 I.T, 2 HR, 2 Personnel.

So my query basically is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `surname`, `job_title`, `company_name`
FROM (`company_database`)
WHERE `employee_code` IN ('6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13')
AND `turnover_code` IN ('5', '6', '7', '8')
AND `contact_code` IN ('16', '17', '26', '27', '9', '10', '30', '31', '23', '24', '12', '13')     AND `industry_code` NOT IN ('22', '17', '35', '36') LIMIT 10
```

But that simply returns a unique row. What i need is one contact per company and no more than 1 contact_code type. I also only want 10 rows returned, but obviously to get this 1 per contact code per row, the query will need to look at more than 10.

Is this possible in just a query? Or should i do something programatically to apply the logic needed to whittle down the results of a query.

Comment: please post schema , some sample data and desired output

Comment: Which one is more important? contact_code or company? It won't be always possible to have "one contact per company and no more than 1 contact_code type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can work with a temporary table using the myisam engine and a trick.

If you create the following temporary table:

```
create table tmp_company_sequence
(  surname varchar(255)
  ,job_title varchar(255)
  ,company_name varchar(255)
  ,date_added date
  ,contact_code int
  ,counter int auto_increment
  ,primary key (contact_code,counter)
);
```

Now

```
insert into `tmp_company_sequence`( `surname`, `job_title`, `company_name`,`contact_code`,`date_added`)
SELECT DISTINCT `surname`, `job_title`, `company_name`,`contact_code`,`date_added`
FROM (`company_database`)
WHERE `employee_code` IN ('6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13')
AND `turnover_code` IN ('5', '6', '7', '8')
AND `contact_code` IN ('16', '17', '26', '27', '9', '10', '30', '31', '23', '24', '12', '13')     AND `industry_code` NOT IN ('22', '17', '35', '36')
order by contact_code, added_date desc;
```

Your temporary table will now hold all the contacts with a counter. The counter is increased for every contact of the same contact_code. SO the newest contact with a certain contact code will have counter = 1, the next recent will have counter = 2 and so on.

You can now do a

```
select * 
from tmp_company_sequence 
order by counter asc, date_added desc 
limit 10;
```

This will give you a list of the latest contacts added over all contact_codes.

Edit:

I just realised this could be done with a single query, but it is even more ugly:

```
SELECT `surname`
  , `job_title`
  , `company_name`
  , `contact_code`
FROM(
  SELECT  
    `surname`
    , `job_title`
    , `company_name`
    , `contact_code`
    , `date_added` 
    , IF(contact_code = @prev_contact_code,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1) AS counter
    , @prev_contact_code = contact_code
  FROM
    (`company_database`)
    ,(SELECT @i := 1) 
  WHERE `employee_code` IN ('6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13') 
    AND `turnover_code` IN ('5', '6', '7', '8') 
    AND `contact_code` IN (
      '16'
      , '17'
      , '26'
      , '27'
      , '9'
      , '10'
      , '30'
      , '31'
      , '23'
      , '24'
      , '12'
      , '13'
    ) 
    AND `industry_code` NOT IN ('22', '17', '35', '36') 
  ORDER BY contact_code
    , added_date DESC) sub
WHERE counter = 1
ORDER BY added_date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This does basically the same as the option with the temporary table, but it creates the counter in the fly by storing data from the previous column in global variables. It is messy but can be used within a single query.

Comment: I think i like your first solution! It's no problem to have a temporary table, so i think for clarities sake i'll go for that one! Thank you!!

Comment: Hmm, your table definition doesn't work, mysql says "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: HI John, the first suggestion only works in MyISAM. SOrry, should have added the ENGONE=MYISAM to the create table statement.